# DNS Zone setting in BIND and Cpanel

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver

I'm using my DNS server to block certain sites. However, I ran into a problem.

Let's say there are the following domains:

- www.example.com
- example.com
- john.example.com
- bob.example.com
- mary.example.com
- katie.example.com
- ...

However, I only want to block www.example.com and example.com by pointing their DNS entries to an invalid IP. All other subdomains should remain intact. However, the problem arises when I add example.com as a zone. Once I did that, all subdomains belong to example.com become "non-existent domain" when I use nslookup. Blocking www.example.com does not create any problem.

Is there any way to create an entry for example.com and still let its subdomains use other authoritative nameservers?

**Update**

I tried what @MikeyB suggested, but `nslookup` still gives me "non-existent domain".

What I did :

1. Create a zone in Cpanel for `example.com`   to point to `A 192.168.1.199` (random ip)
2. edit the SOA of `example.com` and point it to the real nameserver

I was not able to create `NS record *.example.com pointing to the real nameservers.`
Cpanel gives me the error message of

> "invalid NS owner name (wildcard)"

Do I need to add a new zone for `*example.com`? If yes, what IP should I be pointing it to since it's a wildcard domain? Do I point it to the IP of `www.example.com`?

Answer (score 1):

Create a zone for `example.com`.

In that zone, create appropriate records for `example.com` and `www.example.com`.
Then create `NS` records for `*.example.com` pointing to the real nameservers.

That *should* do what you want.